# Weird characters when scraping HTML tables generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, encoding

I'm trying to scrape some data from https://www.flashscore.com/tennis/atp-singles/australian-open-2020/results/

In particular, I'm interested in the "tournament-page-data-results" div in the source code. The data does appear in the HTML source code when I pull it up, but it looks something like this:

```
"SA÷2¬~ZA÷ATP - SINGLES: Australian Open (Australia), hard¬ZEE÷MP4jLdJh¬ZB÷3473162¬ZC÷n5bYULYo¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷6N6d2yER¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷2¬ZH÷9011_MP4jLdJh¬ZJ÷5¬ZL÷/tennis/atp-singles/australian-open/¬ZX÷01110...000Australian O021, hard00000000Australian O027ralia)¬ZHS÷5724¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷ATP - Singles¬~AA÷WEJGUHfb¬AD÷1580633100¬ADE÷1580633100¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Thiem
```

with the real data mixed in with random characters. I have tried to convert from 'utf-8' to 'ascii' but it has the same issue just with different random characters.

What is the proper encoding I need here? Or is there a different approach altogether? I'm scraping with R (rvest package) to avoid opening every page in a browser window. I can switch to Python if that is easier.

Comment: I don't know about your `R (rvest package)` or Python. If you are comfortable with `node` then there is one package `cheerio` which is good for the web scraping without opening the page on browser. With this you will get all the HTML source code.

Comment: It looks as if that source code with the odd characters is actually part of the script that creates the page, rather than the HTML of the displayed page itself.  You might be able to unpick it manually, otherwise you could use something like `RSelenium` to capture the page via an automated browser.

Comment: The data content inside div tournament-page-data-results looks like some kind of obfuscation. Maybe on purpose? There is a pattern to the madness however. If you search for "AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷" (view Source) you will get 124 hits right infront of the players. My guess is that javascript translates the data into valid html on the fly. I do not know how you scrape but with JS support the content is put up in the <div class="sportName tennis>.  I did a test with "Web Scraper" extension for Chrome and got the data with the selector "div.sportName" and type HTML. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have mentioned in the comments, this is not an encoding issue. The text content of the div is written in a type of table markup language which is interpreted by javascript.

You can reverse engineer the parser. To start with, each match is split by a tilde (~) character, and the data fields are split by the "¬" character. Each field is in the form of a key-value pair split by a "÷".

It isn't easy to turn this into a data frame, since the data isn't rectangular. It would be easier to convert to JSON.

Here's an example of how to get some of the fields of interest:

```
"https://www.flashscore.com/tennis/atp-singles/australian-open-2020/results/" %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_node("#tournament-page-data-results") %>% 
  rvest::html_text() %>% strsplit("[~]") %>% unlist() %>% strsplit("\u00ac") %>%
  lapply(function(x) gsub("^.*\u00f7", "", x)) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    y <- as.numeric(grep("\\d{10}", x, value = TRUE))
    y <- as.difftime(y, units = "secs") + as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00")
    x[grep("\\d{10}", x)] <- as.character(y)
    return(x)}) %>% 
  lapply(`[`, -(1:2)) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) x[!grepl("^[[:alnum:]]{8}$", x)]) %>%
  lapply(function(x) grep("[a-z ]", x, value = TRUE)[-c(2,4,6,8)]) %>%
  `[`(-(1:2)) %>%
  {do.call(rbind, .)} %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  `names<-`(c("Date", "Stage", "Player1", "Player2")) %>%
  tibble::as.tibble()
#> # A tibble: 127 x 4
#>    Date                Stage          Player1           Player2          
#>    <chr>               <chr>          <chr>             <chr>            
#>  1 2020-02-02 07:45:00 Final          Djokovic N. (Srb) Thiem D. (Aut)   
#>  2 2020-01-31 07:45:00 Semi-finals    Thiem D. (Aut)    Zverev A. (Ger)  
#>  3 2020-01-30 07:45:00 Semi-finals    Federer R. (Sui)  Djokovic N. (Srb)
#>  4 2020-01-29 07:45:00 Quarter-finals Thiem D. (Aut)    Nadal R. (Esp)   
#>  5 2020-01-29 02:45:00 Quarter-finals Wawrinka S. (Sui) Zverev A. (Ger)  
#>  6 2020-01-28 07:50:00 Quarter-finals Raonic M. (Can)   Djokovic N. (Srb)
#>  7 2020-01-28 03:15:00 Quarter-finals Sandgren T. (Usa) Federer R. (Sui) 
#>  8 2020-01-27 08:05:00 1/8-finals     Rublev A. (Rus)   Zverev A. (Ger)  
#>  9 2020-01-27 07:15:00 1/8-finals     Nadal R. (Esp)    Kyrgios N. (Aus) 
#> 10 2020-01-27 03:15:00 1/8-finals     Medvedev D. (Rus) Wawrinka S. (Sui)
#> # ... with 117 more rows
```